# set different image by getting image's name from out side

Tags: android, android-resources

In my `Widget` i have one `ImageView` , i will receive a code from out side ,these codes are between 1-40 , from other side i have 40 different images in my `drawable` folder which i named them the same as their related code.
now what I want to do it ,by reading one code from outside, show the image which has the same name in the `ImageView`.
for example if i read the code 33, i want to show the image which named 33 in the `ImageVIew`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your images in assets folder and you will be able to pick image by name.
suppose your text is 33 and your image name is 33.png

```
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
String fileName = "33";
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetManager.open(fileName + ".png"));
imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

For a drawable named "33.png" or similar, do this:

```
int redId = getResources().getIdentifier("33", "drawable", this.getPackageName());

img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
```

And, in the general case:

```
void setImageByResourceName(int resourceName) { // 33 in the example above

    String nameStr = String.valueOf(resourceName);

    int redId = getResources().getIdentifier(nameStr, "drawable", this.getPackageName());

    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the Drawable resource given its name with the following method:

```
private static Drawable getDrawableResourceByName(Context context, String resourceName) {
    String packageName = AmbyantApplication.get().getPackageName();
    int resId = AmbyantApplication.get().getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable", packageName);
    if (resId != 0) {
        return context.getResources().getDrawable(resId);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the system for the resource id if you know it's name. For example:

```
int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(
    "33", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

However, this method call is relatively expensive so try to use it sparingly if you must. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)): *"Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name."*

Answer (score 0):

you can have a SparseArray or Hashmap to map your Images to an integer then if an integer receive from server you can set your drawable according to that key.

you can get the image related to your key in sparseArray by

```
SparseArray<E> t = new SparseArray<E>();
e = t.get(key);
.
.
.
```